# Run Cron Job in Background on Linux/Apache

Tags: linux, apache, cron

I have a cron job I need to run every 7 days to aggregate up a bunch of data using a php script.  The process is pretty CPU intensive and can take a decent amount of time.  Despite setting it to run at 4 am (when we get the least amount of traffic) users are starting to notice some down time when the script runs.  Is there a way to run this in the background only when the CPU is not being used or has an open thread?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cron job line, you can wrap the php command line with either the 'nice', 'chrt' or 'loadwatch' programs.